# Como puedo insertar datos a tablas relacionadas usando MySql y PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Mi problema es que no sé me ocurre como puedo insertar datos a mis tablas relacionadas.

[image: Tablas relacionadas]

lo que se me ocurre es insertar datos primero a la tabla erp_far_cab y luego hacer un select a la misma tabla para obtener el ultimo id o registro insertado para así poder insertar datos en la erp_far_det con el id obtenido, todo bien hasta ahí, pero el problema se presenta cuando otro u otros usuarios realizan el mismo proceso al mismo tiempo, en ese caso puede ocurrir que el id obtenido no sea devuelto al usuario correcto.
**¿Existe algún otro método?**

*espero me haya dejado entender,* **gracias de antemano su tiempo y ayuda**

Comment: Deberías ampliar el contexto de tu pregunta, ya que si son catálogos, no deberías de tener ese problema pues debería de existir en la tabla padre antes de insertar en la tabla hija, para que cuando generes en la tabla hija ya lleves el id correspondiente.

Comment: Lo que se suele en esos casos es tener un select que muestre las diferentes opciones, haciendo que se seleccione una de ellas, la cual se inserta en la base de datos. No te fíes de lastInsert, ya que su valor no siempre es correcto, más aún en una bd que podría estar siendo modificada por varios usuarios al mismo tiempo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mi me pasaba igual y lo corregí así.
Contexto: Creo un ticket de soporte. El Ticket y sus propiedades están en una tabla, y los mensajes de los tickets se guardan en otra. Entonces al crear un ticket, tengo que crearlo en la tabla tickets e insertar su mensaje correspondiente en otra tabla. Entonces, creo el ticket y recupero su ID en ese momento y lo regreso a una función en donde inmediatamente inserta el mensaje con el ID recuperado.

me quedó algo así.

Función que crea el ticket:

```
public function crearTicketController($idUsuario, $asunto, $prioridad, $mensaje, $clase){
            $idu= $idUsuario;
            $as= $asunto;
            $p = $prioridad;
            $c =$clase;
            #primero se inserta el ticket y se obtiene el último ID de la tabla ticket
            $idticket = Datos::crearTicketModel($idUsuario, $asunto, $prioridad, $mensaje, $clase);
            #ahora inserto el mensaje
            $respuesta = Datos::mensajeTicketModel($idticket, $idu, $text, $c);
             if($respuesta==1){
                echo '
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                      window.setTimeout(function(){
                            window.location="panel.php?modulo=tickets&action=ver&id='.$idticket.'";
                        }, 0);
                        </script>
                        ';
             }
             else{
                echo "error";
             }                  
        }
```

Función que inserta el ticket:

```
public function crearTicketModel($idUsuario, $asunto, $prioridad, $mensaje, $clase){
        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO tickets (idusuario, asunto, prioridad, fecha, estado) VALUES (:idusuario, :asunto, :prioridad,  now(), 1 )");
        $stmt->bindParam(":idusuario", $idUsuario, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":asunto", $asunto, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":prioridad", $prioridad, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        if($stmt->execute()){
            $stmt= Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT MAX(id) as idTicket FROM tickets");
            if($stmt->execute()){
                $idticket = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $myidticket = $idticket["idTicket"];
                return $myidticket;
            }else{
            $respuesta = $this->mensajeError();
            }
        }else{
            $respuesta = $this->mensajeError();
        }

    }
```

Función que inserta el mensaje del ticket:

```
public function mensajeTicketModel($idTicket, $idUsuario, $mensaje, $clase){
        $id = $idTicket;
        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO detalletickets (idticket, idusuario, texto, fecha, clase) VALUES (:idticket, :idusuario, :mensaje,  now(), :clase )");
        $stmt->bindParam(":idticket", $idTicket, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":idusuario", $idUsuario, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
        $stmt->bindParam(":mensaje", $mensaje, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":clase", $clase, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    if($stmt->execute()){
                        return 1;
                    }
                    else{
                        return 0;
                    }
    }
```

Espero te sirva, de esa manera yo lo resolví y no hay falla. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías poder obtener el id que buscas ejecutando esto luego del insert.

Si usas PDO `PDO::lastInsertId`

Si usas Mysqli `mysqli::$insert_id`

En ambos casos lo que devuelve es por conexión a la base de datos así que no hay problema que haya otros inserts en paralelo.

Ref: [How do I get the last inserted ID of a MySQL table in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685860/how-do-i-get-the-last-inserted-id-of-a-mysql-table-in-php)